# Capture and save image with Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I need help with Kotlin. I need to capture and save an image in my media store.

My code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var ListadeProductos = ArrayList<Notas>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        camera.setOnClickListener {

            val intentCamera = Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE")
            startActivity(intentCamera)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is ... ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This isn't an Android Studio issue, so don't use the Android Studio tag

Answer (score 4):

I think maybe the next code can help you half way. Just capture the image from camera and display it in an ImageView.

I used it (found in *[Creating camera intent app using Kotlin on android - Displaying thumbnail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wbeWN4hQt0)*).

```
val CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 0
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        val callCameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        if (callCameraIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(callCameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when(requestCode) {
        CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE -> {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap)
            }
        }
        else -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unrecognized request code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You "saw" it? Did you tested it before posting or was this just a guess?...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest code is to, open the native camera app to take a picture and handle result in the OnActivityResult method, as shown in the article *[Capture Picture with Camera in Kotlin – Android](https://handyopinion.com/capture-photo-with-camera-in-kotlin-android/)*.

```
val REQUEST_CODE = 200

fun capturePhoto() {

    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE)
}


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && data != null){
        imageView.setImageBitmap(data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap)
    }
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://trickyworld.tech/how-to-take-picture-from-camera-and-show-in-an-image-view-in-android-kotline/) blog explains how take picture from camera and show in an imagview in android/kotlin -- very simple

Comment: Please page is no longer available

Comment: Now the link is working, please check. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Complete code for pick image and crop it

> **Step 1**: Add this gradle

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:1.2.1'
```

> **Step 2**: Add two activities in your package and in manifest

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activities.CropImageActivity"
    android:label="Crop Image"></activity>

<activity android:name=".ui.activities.ImagePickerActivity"
    android:label="Pick Image"></activity>
```

CropImageActivity class

```
public class CropImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CropImageView.OnSetImageUriCompleteListener, CropImageView.OnGetCroppedImageCompleteListener {

    private static final int DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_VALUES = 100;

    public static final String CROPPED_IMAGE_PATH = "cropped_image_path";
    public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE_URI = "cropped_image_path";

    public static final String FIXED_ASPECT_RATIO = "extra_fixed_aspect_ratio";
    public static final String EXTRA_ASPECT_RATIO_X = "extra_aspect_ratio_x";
    public static final String EXTRA_ASPECT_RATIO_Y = "extra_aspect_ratio_y";

    private static final String ASPECT_RATIO_X = "ASPECT_RATIO_X";

    private static final String ASPECT_RATIO_Y = "ASPECT_RATIO_Y";

    private CropImageView mCropImageView;

    private int mAspectRatioX = DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_VALUES;

    private int mAspectRatioY = DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_VALUES;

    private boolean isFixedAspectRatio = false;

    Bitmap croppedImage;
    //endregion

    private TextView tv_cancel, tv_crop;

    // Saves the state upon rotating the screen/restarting the activity
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems") Bundle bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        bundle.putInt(ASPECT_RATIO_X, mAspectRatioX);
        bundle.putInt(ASPECT_RATIO_Y, mAspectRatioY);
    }

    // Restores the state upon rotating the screen/restarting the activity
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems") Bundle bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle);
        mAspectRatioX = bundle.getInt(ASPECT_RATIO_X);
        mAspectRatioY = bundle.getInt(ASPECT_RATIO_Y);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop_image);
        tv_cancel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_cancel);
        tv_crop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_crop);
        if (!getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_URI)) {
            cropFailed();
            return;
        }

        isFixedAspectRatio = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(FIXED_ASPECT_RATIO, false);
        mAspectRatioX = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ASPECT_RATIO_X, DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_VALUES);
        mAspectRatioY = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ASPECT_RATIO_Y, DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_VALUES);

        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_URI));

        // Initialize components of the app
        mCropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);

        // If you want to fix the aspect ratio, set it to 'true'
        mCropImageView.setFixedAspectRatio(isFixedAspectRatio);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mCropImageView.setImageUriAsync(imageUri);
        }

        tv_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cropFailed();
            }
        });

        tv_crop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCropImageView.getCroppedImageAsync(mCropImageView.getCropShape(), 0, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    private void cropFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(mCropImageView.getContext(), "Image crop failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mCropImageView.setOnSetImageUriCompleteListener(this);
        mCropImageView.setOnGetCroppedImageCompleteListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mCropImageView.setOnSetImageUriCompleteListener(null);
        mCropImageView.setOnGetCroppedImageCompleteListener(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSetImageUriComplete(CropImageView view, Uri uri, Exception error) {
        if (error == null) {
            //Toast.makeText(mCropImageView.getContext(), "Image load successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            //Toast.makeText(mCropImageView.getContext(), "Image load failed: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(mCropImageView.getContext(), "Unable to load image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onGetCroppedImageComplete(CropImageView view, Bitmap bitmap, Exception error) {
        if (error == null) {
            croppedImage = bitmap;
            try {
                String path = saveToInternalStorage(this, bitmap);
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra(CROPPED_IMAGE_PATH, path);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                finish();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                cropFailed();
            }
        }
        else {
            cropFailed();
        }
    }

    private String saveToInternalStorage(Context context, Bitmap bitmapImage) throws IOException {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);

        // Path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Create imageDir
        File mypath = new File(directory, "image.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            //Bitmap scaledBitmap = getCompressedBitmap(bitmapImage);
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, fos);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            fos.close();
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

#### ImagePickerActivity class

```
public class ImagePickerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE = 2365;
    private static final int REQUEST_CROP_IMAGE = 2342;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startActivityForResult(getPickImageChooserIntent(), REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImageActivity.class);
                Uri imageUri = getPickImageResultUri(data);
                intent.putExtra(CropImageActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE_URI, imageUri.toString());
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CROP_IMAGE);
            }
            else
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_CROP_IMAGE) {
                    System.out.println("Image crop success:" + data.getStringExtra(CropImageActivity.CROPPED_IMAGE_PATH));
                    String imagePath = new File(data.getStringExtra(CropImageActivity.CROPPED_IMAGE_PATH), "image.jpg").getAbsolutePath();
                    Intent result = new Intent();
                    result.putExtra("image_path", imagePath);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
                    finish();
                }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Image crop failed");
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a chooser intent to select the source to get image from.<br/>
     * The source can be camera's (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) or gallery's (ACTION_GET_CONTENT).<br/>
     * All possible sources are added to the intent chooser.
     */
    public Intent getPickImageChooserIntent() {

        // Determine URI of camera image to save.
        Uri outputFileUri = getCaptureImageOutputUri();

        List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

        // Collect all camera intents
        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
            if (outputFileUri != null) {
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            }
            allIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // Collect all gallery intents
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        List<ResolveInfo> listGallery = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listGallery) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(galleryIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
            allIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // The main intent is the last in the list, so pickup the useless one
        Intent mainIntent = allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);
        for (Intent intent : allIntents) {
            if (intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals("com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity")) {
                mainIntent = intent;
                break;
            }
        }
        allIntents.remove(mainIntent);

        // Create a chooser from the main intent
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(mainIntent, "Select source");

        // Add all other intents
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));

        return chooserIntent;
    }

    /**
     * Get URI to image received from capture by camera.
     */
    private Uri getCaptureImageOutputUri() {
        Uri outputFileUri = null;
        File getImage = getExternalCacheDir();
        if (getImage != null) {
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getImage.getPath(), "pickImageResult.jpeg"));
        }
        return outputFileUri;
    }

    /**
     * Get the URI of the selected image from {@link #getPickImageChooserIntent()}.<br/>
     * Will return the correct URI for camera and gallery image.
     *
     * @param data the returned data of the activity result
     */
    public Uri getPickImageResultUri(Intent data) {
        boolean isCamera = true;
        if (data != null) {
            String action = data.getAction();
            isCamera = action != null && action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
        return isCamera ? getCaptureImageOutputUri() : data.getData();
    }
}
```

activity_crop_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorblue"
        android:padding="15dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_crop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="Crop"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
        android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cropFixAspectRatio="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> **Step 3**: Usage in fragment or activity class

```
private val REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE = 1002
profile_pic1.setOnClickListener {
    startActivityForResult(Intent(activity, ImagePickerActivity::class.java), REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE)
}


fun setImage(imagePath: String) {
    profile_pic1.setImageBitmap(getImageFromStorage(imagePath));
}

fun getImageFromStorage(path: String): Bitmap {
    var f = File(path);
    var options = BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 512, 512);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(FileInputStream(f), null, options)
}

private fun calculateInSampleSize(
        options: BitmapFactory.Options, reqWidth: Int, reqHeight: Int): Int {

    // Raw height and width of image
    val height = options.outHeight
    val width = options.outWidth
    var inSampleSize = 1

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        val halfHeight = height / 2
        val halfWidth = width / 2

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while (halfHeight / inSampleSize > reqHeight && halfWidth / inSampleSize > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == requestCode) {
        var imagePath = data!!.getStringExtra("image_path");
        setImage(imagePath);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Failed to load image");
    }
}
```

> **NOTE: declare write/read and camera permission in the manifest and
>   runtime permissions as well**

Comment: Why would you use a library and still write plenty codes like this then what's its purpose?